# co-ordinates of object change, but visually it doesnt move?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

i have a falling object airplane sim whose coodinates fall, but the object doesn't visually move.  does anyone know why that might happen?

I have tried putting a box collider on it, but that would ruin aerodynamic simulation...and i didn't have to put a box collider on my main car object.

Comment: Does your plain have a Rigidbody attached? and marked as Kinematic? Could also be that the object that is holding the changing coordinates are not the same that the gameObject holding the mesh of the plain¿?

Comment: Have you parented the camera to the falling object?

Comment: i think i fixed it now, my rigidbody parent to all components [ airplane ] is the only rigid body.